# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jetbrains/kotlin/annotation/plugin/ide/AnnotationBasedPluginModelBuilderService

Tags: android, kotlin

I getting this error in my java project. I am not able to disable the kotlin plugin from IDE, and my kotlin plugin is latest updated.

Comment: invalidate cache and restart!

Comment: Not working tried

Comment: then try deleting gradle cache `.../.gradle/caches` and sync again

Comment: I am having the same issue. I don't think it's a bug with gradle cache. I have an almost identical copy of the same project which builds successfully.  Also other projects build no problem. Tried deleting every cache in the project didn't work either. Removing Android Studio cache doesn't work too.

Answer (score 2):

> NoClassDefFoundError:org/jetbrains/kotlin/annotation/plugin/ide/AnnotationBasedPluginModelBuilderService

I solved this issue by updating Kotlin plugin.

Go to:

> Tools > Kotlin > Configure Kotlin Plugin Updates > Check for update

If you found a new version, please update it and restart your IDE.

Comment: He specifically said his Kotlin plugin was up to date. How does this help?

Comment: Didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Couldn't believe at first especially because it happened for only one of my projects. But turned out it was caused by a hard drive error: Cyclic Redundancy Check or CRC. Meaning your hard drive fails to read the package files containing these classes.
Run check disk and then uninstall Android studio and all related files including `[Windows drive]:/Users/[your user]/.gradle` and `.androidstudio*`. Then download and install Android studio again. It should get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**Ksp conflict with KGP, which causes failures with Android Studio**

```
ksp-1.8.10-1.0.9 is too old for kotlin-1.8.21.
Please upgrade ksp or downgrade kotlin-gradle-plugin to 1.8.10.
```

Upgrading ksp to
`"1.8.21-1.0.11"` solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

try to delete the global cache, that is `C:\Users\<name>\.gradle\caches\` on windows.